# Store image in sql server

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim myfilelocation As String = "C:\myPictures\myimage.png"
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=MUSTAFA\MUSTAFA;Initial Catalog=Tijaabo;User ID=sa;Password=123")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into customers(CustomerID,fname) Values('" & CustomerIDTextBox.Text & "','" & FnameTextBox.Text & "')", conn)

        Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("update customers set photo = @picturebox where CustomerID=" + CustomerIDTextBox.Text, conn)

Dim param As New SqlParameter("@picturebox", SqlDbType.VarBinary) 

        Dim ImageData As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(myfilelocation)
        param.Value = ImageData
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", 3)
        Try
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub
```

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Here are my questions:

1. Since the application is storing in database, how can I retrieve that code into the vb.net because I can't see it in database?
2. You can see the image is getting its path location from my machine as local so I want to either put it somewhere where other computers in workgroup can able to get the images or how to tell other computers to store the image in my machine and to retrieve it from here.

Comment: What have you done? i mean, did you edit it or what? i need help and tell me what your suggestions are, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your aim is to store an image in a database so there is no need to store it in network or make your computer accessible.

The picture is not in the database because you don't run the `cmd1` command.